# How can I populate a class which is defined as the intersection of two other classes?

Tags: rdf, owl, protege

I'm trying to create an intersection with Protege.

I have created two classes, A and B. Class A contains two individuals, John and Mary. Class B also contains two individuals, Jane and Mary. I have then created a class AB, which I have defined as the intersection of A and B.

[image]

Since the individual Mary is part of Class A and Class B, I was expecting it to be added to the class AB. But when I ran the reasoner (Hermit), nothing happened. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "But when I ran the reasoner (Hermit), nothing happened."  What do you mean?  If you browse to the Individuals tab and select Mary you don't see the class AB as one of its types? If you go to the DL Query tab and enter AB (and check the individuals checkbox), you don't see Mary listed?  What does "nothing happens" means? What did you expect to happen? You haven't given us enough to help diagnose the problem, or even know what the problem is yet.

Comment: I mean that the class AB doesn't contain any individuals.
I expected the individual Mary to be added to the class AB by the reasoner. I don't know how to make that any clearer.

Comment: "I expected the individual Mary to be added to the class AB by the reasoner." Well, that right there could mean some different things.  How do you *check* whether "the individual Mary to be added to the class AB"?  Because Protégé shows the results of reasoners in different ways, so even if the reasoner does infer that Mary is an AB, that result might not appear everywhere might expect it to.  For instance, in the screenshot you've posted, I don't see anywhere that I'd expect "Mary" to appear.  (Perhaps if you scroll down in the "Description: AB" panel, there might be a list of individuals?)

Comment: The reason that I ask for clarification is that (quoting from the reasons for closing questions): "Questions seeking debugging help ('why isn't this code working?') must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.** Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."   It's obvious that you've got a problem, but you haven't provided us with your ontology, or told us what specific behavior you expect but aren't seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your example, and you are not doing anything wrong.
When I select Mary, it inferrs that it is from the type AB. The inference does not show when browsing the class, but when selecting the individual. Maybe that was why you got confused.
See my screenshot for details:
[image]

Answer (score -2):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>


<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [
    <!ENTITY owl "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" >
    <!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >
]>


<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.semanticweb.org/i.gurjanov/ontologies/2014/8/untitled-ontology-6#"
     xml:base="http://www.semanticweb.org/i.gurjanov/ontologies/2014/8/untitled-ontology-6"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/i.gurjanov/ontologies/2014/8/untitled-ontology-6"/>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Classes
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/i.gurjanov/ontologies/2014/8/untitled-ontology-6#A -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/i.gurjanov/ontologies/2014/8/untitled-ontology-6#A">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&owl;Thing"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/i.gurjanov/ontologies/2014/8/untitled-ontology-6#AB -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/i.gurjanov/ontologies/2014/8/untitled-ontology-6#AB">
        <owl:equivalentClass>
            <owl:Class>
                <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/i.gurjanov/ontologies/2014/8/untitled-ontology-6#A"/>
                    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/i.gurjanov/ontologies/2014/8/untitled-ontology-6#B"/>
                </owl:intersectionOf>
            </owl:Class>
        </owl:equivalentClass>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/i.gurjanov/ontologies/2014/8/untitled-ontology-6#B -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/i.gurjanov/ontologies/2014/8/untitled-ontology-6#B">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&owl;Thing"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Individuals
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/i.gurjanov/ontologies/2014/8/untitled-ontology-6#Mary -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/i.gurjanov/ontologies/2014/8/untitled-ontology-6#Mary">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/i.gurjanov/ontologies/2014/8/untitled-ontology-6#A"/>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/i.gurjanov/ontologies/2014/8/untitled-ontology-6#B"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
</rdf:RDF>



<!-- Generated by the OWL API (version 3.5.0) http://owlapi.sourceforge.net -->
```

Comment: Is this an answer? If so, please don't just dump code. Please add an explanation.

Comment: You have a significant amount of comment / white-space in your code snippet.  You should try to minify your code comments and line breaks so that it takes up less space but not minified to the point in which it's unreadable.  It's also encouraged to explain your code rather than code only answers.  The original poster may likely not understand how your code works.

Comment: Mary must be instance of A. Mary must be instance of B. Add both classes in Types (Entities tab) of Mary or just ctrl+c and ctrl+v my code and look for difference